# How to get responsiveness from Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.5

Is there a metric that I can pull from the Facebook Graph API that would tell me either/both `Response Rate` and/or `Average Response Time` from a page?

I'll attach a screenshot as to what I'm referring to:

[image]

I'm seeing this when I go to Settings -> Insights -> Messages, but would love to know how to pull this information from Facebook.

Anyone know the specific metrics or queries I could use to obtain this information?

**EDIT**: For anyone who offers the `displayed_message_response_time`, this doesn't work because it is set by the user AND returns a string (not numeric value).

Comment: Ok, yeah, guess I should have tested myself what that property returns, and not rely on the description in the manual. I'll remove that answer.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Afaik there is only one way to get the reaction time:

- Use `/page-id/feed?fields=id,from` to get all posts with the info who created them
- Filter out the user posts with the "from" field
- Get the time between the user post and a page answer (if there is one) post by post
- Calculate the average response time based on the resulting times

I believe Fanpage Karma does it that way.